# How to set up a default font when adding a product

Tags: magento-1.9

We use a specific font and size for all of our product descriptions etc when setting up a new product in Magento. Is there any way we can set our preferences as a default to save changing it every time?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class name to a tag you add to description, and all descriptions within this class name will use your settings. So, in description textarea, you can use something like that: `<div class="custom-font">...your description...</div>` and in your css file, you then add a rule:

```
.custom-font {
  font-family: 'something';
  font-size: 'Npx';
  ..
}
```

And you can use this class name as many times as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If that is text area then you can write html into that

`<div class="myclass"> yourdesc </div>`

and in your css file

```
.myclass{
   font-family:'myfontfamily'; 
   color:'#123456';
   font-size:'18px';
  }
```